# How to create a Composite Primary Key in SAP PowerDesigner

Tags: sql, powerdesigner

I have a join table and I would like to create a composite primary key for it, like so:

```
PRIMARY KEY ('table1fk' , 'table2fk')
```

How would I do this via the SAP PowerDesigner table/column editor?

Answer (score 0):

After joining your table to the other tables, you mark the Foreign Key migrated from the other tables, as Primary Key.

[image]

Which gives the following SQL script:

```
create table PARTICIPATION (
POLL_ID              int                  not null,
USER_ID              int                  not null,
primary key (POLL_ID, USER_ID),
foreign key (POLL_ID)
      references POLL (ID),
foreign key (USER_ID)
      references "USER" (ID)
);
```